# Grouping inline elements in nav bar into two groups and prevent wrapping within a group

Tags: css

I'm new so I have no idea if this is even possible, searching the site and internet was rather fruitless.

I have a horizontal nav bar with five images that wrap as expected when the window size is reduced. What I would like to do is prevent the first three items from wrapping between themselves, and prevent the last two items from wrapping between themselves as well. Basically, when the window gets small enough, the last two items should wrap under the first three items, and that's it. Nothing else should wrap in any other way.

A picture says a thousand words:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb0Oy.jpg

This is my situation:

```
<style>

#nav {
display: block;
list-style: none;
}

#nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
text-align:center;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#nav img {  
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
vertical-align: top;
margin-left: 45px;
margin-right: 45px;
}

</style>



<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li id="i1"><img src="images/minu-about-blue.png" width="141" height="36" />
<li id="i2"><img src="images/menu-mixes-blue.png" width="130" height="36" />
<li id="i3"><img src="images/menu-guestbook-blue.png" width="250" height="36" />
<li id="i4"><img src="images/menu-links-blue.png" width="125" height="36" />
<li id="i5"><img src="images/menu-other-blue.png" width="137" height="36" />
</ul>
</div>
```

The main wrapper I have the page in also has the following properties, I know it can be relevant in some circumstances:

```
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done unless you split it into two `<ul>` groups, one for the first group of 3 and one for the group of 2.

Comment: Just tried it out, perfectly sufficient for my current needs, thanks. Seems somewhat "improper" but it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are going to want to use media queries to detect screen with and adjust the margins of each image to get the desired result.

Something like this.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#nav img {  
margin-left: 85px;
margin-right: 85px;
}
}
```

This is a very general answer, for a very general question. I would certainly study responsive CSS.

Comment: I'm just starting out and my main objective is to put out my website in the layout I have in mind, or close enough as long as it's aesthetic. I will most certainly study further and likely re-code it more "properly" as I gain more knowledge, maybe even from the bottom up on a fluid grid foundation after I gain more experience.

Comment: http://www.cleverogre.com/cssfun/
I think this is what you had in mind, view source to see the code.

Comment: Thanks, the way they wrap is what I had in mind, yes, but the images are not all the same width and should keep their original width despite browser resize, this stretches the images. Also some kind of max-width setting for the whole container to make them wrap before reaching the edges of a resized screen.